# Rails & Shopify API: Get the most recent 5 customers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've read the [Shopify API docs](https://docs.shopify.com/api/order) but I can't figure out how I would call this in my app

I thought this would work: `ShopifyAPI::Customer.limit(5)`  but it throws an error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for ShopifyAPI::Customer:Class

Any ideas? I can find all the endpoints in the docs, but can't find much about interacting in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but:

```
ShopifyAPI::Customer.find(:all, :params => {:limit => 5})
```